# Can you skip parts of an array when using a for-each loop?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

I was told to only return strings with a given length from an array. I can do this easy with a regular for loop. but I recently discovered for-each loops and I am trying to learn how to use them. this problem seems doable but I may be wrong.

There is the code I am working on:

```
public List wordsWithoutList(String[] words, int len) {
    String[] temp = new String[0];
    for (String i : words) {
        if (i.length() != len) {
            temp = new String[temp.length + 1];
            temp[i] = words[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: The title and the question doesn’t go together. What is your question?

Comment: Just put an `if...` inside your for-loop.

Comment: Please show the example of code you are working on

Comment: there is the  code im working on

Answer (score 0):

That's not the point of a for **each** loop. You can skip elements (continue) or break out of the loop (break), but you have to call the body for each element.

When you want to just handle a specified range of indexes use the "normal" for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.
The big difference between a `for` loop and a `foreach` loop is to obfuscate the iterator from the loop, so you don't have to worry about requirements. Otherwise, they work very similarly.
To answer your question - if you add a conditional statement to check for what you don't want, you can "skip" using the `continue` keyword. `continue` works like `break`, but instead of breaking the loop, it simply skips the processing for the current iteration.
You can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-making-javaif-else-switch-break-continue-jump/) at Geeks for Geeks.

Answer (score 0):

To return strings with a given length from an array you could use simple `if` statement:

```
public List<String> givenLength(String[] words, int len) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() == len) {
            strings.add(word);
        }
    }
    return strings;
}
```